# sass, custom selectors based on parent

Tags: css, sass, bem

I have the following mixins to make easy work with BEM syntax, `sass 3.3.2` code:

```
=b($name)
  .#{$name}
    @content

=e($name)
  &__#{$name}
    @content

=m($name)
  &--#{$name}
    @content

+b(menu)
  +e(item)
    color: grey
  +e(item)
    +m(alert)
      color: red
```

This gives me the desired result:

```
.menu__item {color: grey;}
.menu__item--alert {color: red;}
```

So this works pretty nice for element level modifiers, however when i want to have block level modifiers the problem begins:

```
+b(menu)
  +m(theme-1)
    +e(item)
      color: blue
```

css output:

```
.menu--theme-1__item {color: blue;}
```

when the thing i really want is this:

```
.menu--theme-1 .menu__item {color: blue;}
```

So i need a way to check what the context of an element is, when the context is a block there is no problem but when is a modifier the syntax fails. I tried inside e mixin to take the parent selector as string, so when `e` parent is `b` it will not have the `--` syntax, in the other way when his parent is `m` it will have the `--` syntax, with that i could decide what syntax use for both context.
I didn't find a way to take the parent selector as a string and i think is not possible, is there a way to make this works?

**Update**
I found a not very straightforward solution with it works fine, it uses a context argument in the element mixin:

```
=e($name, $context:null)
  @if $context
    &
      +b($context)
        &__#{$name}
          @content
  @else
    &__#{$name}
      @content
```

Now i can call the mixin as follows:

```
+b(menu)
  +m(theme-1)
    +e(item, nav)
      color: blue
```

getting:

```
.menu--theme-1 .menu__item {color: blue;}
```

Comment: +1 -- I was about to ask this very question.

Answer (score 0):

Answering a 2 year old question - long shot :) But hopefully could help someone else as well.

So a more robust way would be to improve your Element mixin to check if the parent selector has a modifier.

So you would need 2 functions:

- one to check if a selector contains a modifier
- one to get the block name from that selector

```css
@function _bem-selector-has-modifier($selector) {
  $selector: _bem-selector-to-string($selector);

  @if str-index($selector, $bem-modifier-separator) or str-index($selector, ':') {
    @return true;
  } @else {
    @return false;
  }
}


@function _bem-get-block-name($selector) {
  $selector: _bem-selector-to-string($selector);
  $modifier-separator: '--';

  $modifier-start: str-index($selector, $modifier-separator) - 1;

  @return str-slice($selector, 0, $modifier-start);
}
```

And then you just need to apply the check in your element mixin

```css
$bem-element-separator: '__';

@mixin element($element) {
  $selector: &;

  @if _bem-selector-has-modifier($selector) {
    $block: _bem-get-block-name($selector);

    @at-root {
      #{$selector} {
        .#{$block + '__' + $element} {
          @content;
        }
      }
    }
  } @else {
    @at-root {
      #{$selector +'__' + $element} {
        @content;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So calling `element('item')` inside a `modifier('with-modifier')` should render a `.block--with-modifier .block__item` selector in your compiled CSS and you won't have to manually pass the context.

The code posted is SCSS, but the idea should be the same with SASS.